# Difference between Label.setScale and Label.setFontScale?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

Both methods are not documented both and does not seem to behave as I would expect.

`mylabel.setFontScale(3f);` makes the apparent text 3 times larger (what I'm looking for) but does not center properly when using it with `Align.center`.

`mylabel.setScale(3f);` does nothing as far as I could see.

What is the difference between those 2 methods and what one should I use to make my label bigger and properly centered ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setFontScale()` indeed enlarges the font, this is often unwanted since scaling up pixelizes the font.

`label.setScale()` does work if you are not using a layout actor like a table. When actors go inside a layout then the layout is responsible for setting the sizes and position. For example, you have control over this once you put it inside a table cell.

```
table.add(myLabel).width(300).height(80).padLeft(100).expandX();
```

[Detailed documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table) on working with a table.

This however just sizes the label, not the text inside. You can still do `setFontScale(3f)` but this will pixelate the font. You have 2 better options:

- create a extra bitmap font in Hiero 3 times larger.
- Use `Gdx.Freetype` to import a `.ttf` and generate fonts on run-time.

Comment: I'm using the distance font shader so I'm fine with scaling. What If I'm just using a Group with setPosition to place my Label ? Anyway, you answer the original question pretty well, thank you.

Comment: Not sure, group does not use cells and does not implement `Layout` so I guess then `setScale()` should work. But I'm on my phone and have no IDE available to test it out.